# How do I safely upgrade from Windows 7 + Ubuntu dual-boot to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, windows-10

I'll begin with a disclaimer: this is a borderline "discussion" question, so please forgive me if it seems out of place.

I have a laptop running Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I'd like to update it to Windows 10, removing my Ubuntu installation during the upgrade as I no longer use it. My installation includes

1. A Windows partition (C://),
2. Ubuntu system / swap partitions, which I'd like to format and merge into C://, and
3. A shared partition (D://) that both Windows and Ubuntu use to store data, which I would like to merge back into the Windows partition (C://).

What is the safest way to navigate this potential quagmire during my upgrade so I end up with a single Windows 10 partition and a system running only Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is you should remove the ubuntu first like:

### Manual process:

1. Delete the ubuntu partion form windows disk-management Utility.
2. Merge the free space to C:/ drive.
3. Insert your windows CD/bootable usb.
4. When it ask for product key press +F10 it will give you command prompt.
5. type the following: bootrec.exe /fixmbr
6. Reboot the system.

### Third party Software Process:

1. Boot to windows.
2. Install Easy BCD latest version software.
3. Select BCD Deployment Menu option in Easy BCD.
4. Check option Windows Vista/7 bootloader to MBR.
5. Click to Write MBR.
6. Go to Edit Boot Menu in Easy BCD.
7. Make sure that windows 8 option is selected and check the option "skip boot menu."
8. Save setting.
9. Open Disk Management Utility from control panel(It is in Administrative Tools).
10. Delete the ubuntu partion.
11. Merge the partion to C:/
12. Reboot the system.